# Angular catching a 404 file not found error while using ngx-doc-viewer

Tags: html, angular, typescript, ngx-doc-viewer

I have implemented ngx-doc-viewer to be able to render docx files in my webapp. Since the webapp is multilanguage, I do have different docx for every implemented language and I do load the correct docx, depending on the current language selected. Now I would like to handle the scenario where the docx file of a certain language is, for some reason, missing which will lead me to load a default docx file (let's say the english one). I think I need to somehow catch the response error I get in the console, when the component cannot find the target file, but I don't know how. Can you help me please? Thanks!!

Here's some of my code:

HTML:

```
<mat-dialog-content class="text">
    <ngx-doc-viewer [url]="docUrl" [viewer]="viewer"></ngx-doc-viewer>
</mat-dialog-content>
```

TS:

```
import { Component, Inject, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { MAT_DIALOG_DATA } from '@angular/material/dialog';
import { viewerType } from 'ngx-doc-viewer';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-privacy-text',
  templateUrl: './privacy-text.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./privacy-text.component.scss']
})
export class PrivacyTextComponent implements OnInit {

  docLanguage = navigator.language.split('-')[1].toString().toLocaleLowerCase();

  viewer: viewerType; // google, office, mammoth, pdf, url
  docUrl = '';

  constructor(
    @Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public data: {width: string, height: string}) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.viewer = 'mammoth';
    this.docUrl = 'assets/docs/terms_and_conditions-' + this.docLanguage + ".docx";
  }

}
```

CONSOLE error msg:

GET http://localhost:4200/assets/docs/terms_and_conditions-it.docx   [HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found 5ms]

Response:

Cannot GET /assets/docs/terms_and_conditions-it.docx

Comment: The easiest solution will be to set array with supported languages and then check if the supported lang array includes docLanguage. If not then set the docLanguage to default one

Comment: That is not bad at all, but in this case I will have to add or remove a specific element from the array, whenever a new doc file will be added or removed. In "my" way, I would not touch a line in the code, if files change, because the app will just load a default text file, if for whatever reason, if it cannot find the target file.

Comment: Option two:
Create response.interceptor -> check if response code 404 and url path includes assets, then handle 404 error and retry request with default url path